# Process.Start() win32 exception cannot find a file C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, winapi, cmd

I am trying to make a program that connects to a ssh server and then logs me in.
I have successfully created tracert or ping commands, but ssh connection doesn't work for me at all.
I am getting an Exception: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'". I have tried many things, but none of these helped. Problem happens on             Process connect = Process.Start(loginr);

I am doing it in C#, Windows Forms. Visual Studio 2019

Code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = textBox6.Text;
    string password = textBox8.Text;
    string ipaddress = textBox12.Text;
    string log = ("ssh " + "ssh://" + username + "@server:port");
    ProcessStartInfo loginr = new ProcessStartInfo(log);
    ProcessStartInfo passwd = new ProcessStartInfo(password);
    ProcessStartInfo checkhost = new ProcessStartInfo("check-host", ipaddress);
    checkhost.UseShellExecute = false;
    checkhost.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    checkhost.CreateNoWindow = true;
    Process connect = Process.Start(loginr);
    timer2.Start();
    Process logging = Process.Start(passwd);
    timer2.Stop();
    timer1.Start();
    var proc = Process.Start(checkhost);
    timer1.Stop();
    string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    textBox10.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    textBox10.Text = output;
}
```

Also if you find another mistakes in my code I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: Either add the fully-qualified filename or add the path to the environment variable for the process.

Comment: On the newer Windows 10 versions there is by default `%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH` with 64-bit `ssh.exe`. The __system__ environment variable `Path` contains also `%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH` on newer Windows 10. But that is of no help for applications compiled as 32-bit applications because of [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) as there is no 32-bit version of OpenSSH. Therefore `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OpenSSH` is not found at all.

Comment: A 32-bit C# application must use [Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder) to get the path of the Windows directory (usually `C:\Windows`) and concatenate this path with `"\\Sysnative\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe"` to get the fully qualified file name of the SSH executable. Then the C# coded 32-bit application can check if this file exists at all and if that is the case, it can be used with [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo).

Comment: There could be also used .net SSH libraries like [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET). See also the Stack Overflow questions and answers found with [\[c#\] ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+ssh).

Comment: We can easily connect by ssh in CMD and when I type that "ssh " + "ssh://" + username + "@server:port" it works perfectly. Just my program doesn't work and throws me an exception. Ping or tracert commands work fine.

Comment: @PatrykTrzaska You started CMD by executing from Windows shell the executable `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`. So you started the 64-bit version of `cmd.exe`. Browse in Windows File Explorer to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and start the 32-bit version of the Windows command processor with a double click. Now in the 32-bit command prompt environment try to run the `ssh` command lines without using full qualified path `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe` and you will see that 32-bit `cmd.exe` fails to find the 64-bit executable `ssh.exe` as described by Microsoft and me above.